# how many times a file has been downloaded

Tags: c#

I am creating a web browser using C#, and I need to get specific data from the web pages that are loaded in my browser.

The pages I am loading is a download scripts. The data I want to get is: the number of times the file has been downloaded.

I want to save this value in text.

What code can I use for this, or where can I start? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean how many times it's been downloaded by your browser?

Comment: If you are creating a web browser, you better bone up on your dom manipulation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most web browsers have their own storage. [Mozilla uses SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html) for some things.

Whenever your app/browser needs to retrieve a remote resource (URL of any kind), simply log it to a database table.

Perhaps use SQLite yourself for this. A decent start would be to create a history table like this:

```
URL           --varchar(max)
LastAccessed  --datetime
TotalRequests --int
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file that the users will be downloading, you could add a global static int and increment it every time the file is downloaded.